# Does a code change invalidate the archive before uploading app to iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, archive

Just before hitting "Distribute" for my app in iTunes Connect, I  noticed that I made a mistake in my code. So I went and fixed it. But, since I changed something, does that mean that my archive changed as well?

If my archive is no longer the same as my app's current state since I edited that one piece, does that mean that I can simply make a new archive? Or do I have to go through the entire process of filling in meta data, provisioning, and so on before uploading my app?

Answer (score 1):

In a word yes; change to the code means that the previous archive is now out of date. You'll have to go through the process again to create a new one for submission.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I don't really want to go through the whole process again, but it'll be worth it. I appreciate your response. :)

Comment: No problem, I've been there too when I was creating my first iOS app :)

Comment: if you could mark this as answered that would be great! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've already done that, making successive archives of an app before I uploaded the one I wanted. You'll just see a list in your Organizer of all your archives of the app sorted by time/date.  Just make sure you select the right one out of the list when you click the Validate and Distribute buttons.